# Play 2 bower webjar locate

Tags: bower, playframework-2.3, webjars

Right now i have configured and working webjar-based Play 2.3.8 application. Recently i tried to use one of [bower webjars](http://www.webjars.org/bower) in it and did not succeed.

More accurately i have

- `"org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.3.0-2"` and `"org.webjars.bower" % "classnames" % "1.1.4"` in the `plugins.sbt`
- `GET           /webjars/*file                   controllers.WebJarAssets.at(file)` in the `app/routes`
- `<script src="@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.locate("classnames.js"))"></script>` in some `app/views/{file}.scala.html`

With all that i'm receiving

> IllegalArgumentException: classnames.js could not be found. Make sure
>   you've added the corresponding WebJar and please check for typos.

on that page.

Answer (score 0):

The error is accurate.  That Bower WebJar doesn't have a file named `classnames.js` in it: http://www.webjars.org/listfiles/org.webjars.bower/classnames/1.1.4

The upstream Bower project doesn't have a file with that name either: https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames